# K8s coreDNS plugin k8s_external seems not work in my k8s cluster

Tags: kubernetes, external, coredns

I enable k8s_external in my k8s cluster, but it seem not work.

the corefile is updated as below:

```
kubernetes cluster.local
k8s_external bcmt01.nokia.com
```

and then I delete coredns pod to let the updated corefile take effect. then I create a service is as below:

```
kubectl get svc NAME TYPE CLUSTER-IP EXTERNAL-IP PORT(S) AGE 
kubernetes ClusterIP 10.254.0.1 443/TCP 7d20h 
ncs-1-dsx-1 LoadBalancer 10.254.203.4 135.111.190.183 22389:30944/TCP,8989:32634/TCP 48m 
ncs-1-dsx-3 LoadBalancer 10.254.203.3 135.111.190.180 22389:30387/TCP,8989:30697/TCP 2d20h
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

when I try curl ncs-1-dsx-1.default.svc.cluster.local:22389, it works and curl 135.111.190.183:22389, it works but curl ncs-1-dsx-1.default.svc.bcmt01.nokia.com:22389, it does not work. which I miss or wrong? could you give some help?

Answer (score 0):

The way the `k8s_external` plugin works skips the `svc` bit. Try `ncs-1-dsx-1.default.bcmt01.nokia.com` instead or include the `svc.` in the zone.

Comment: thanks for the reply, try but it still fail:(   as below:  [root@bcmt-01-control-01 coredns]# curl ncs-1-dsx-1.default.bcmt01.nokia.com:22389
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: ncs-1-dsx-1.default.bcmt01.nokia.com; Unknown error
[root@bcmt-01-control-01 coredns]

Answer (score 0):

I used to run below commands. `dig` command seems to succeed, but `ping` & `curl` fail, as below:

```sh
[root@bcmt-01-control-01 coredns]# kubectl -n kube-system get svc|grep dns
kube-dns                    ClusterIP   10.254.0.10      <none>  53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP   8d
```

```
[root@bcmt-01-control-01 coredns]# dig @10.254.0.10 ncs-1-dsx-1.default.bcmt01.nokia.com +short
135.111.190.183
```

```
[root@bcmt-01-control-01 coredns]# curl ncs-1-dsx-1.default.bcmt01.nokia.com:22389
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: ncs-1-dsx-1.default.bcmt01.nokia.com; Unknown error
```

```
[root@bcmt-01-control-01 coredns]# curl 135.111.190.183:22389
0▒0x▒)
The client sent a request to the Directory Server that could not be properly decoded as an ASN.1 element:  com.unboundid.asn1.ASN1Exception: Unable to decode the provided ASN.1 element ASN1Element(type=47, valueLength=69, valueBytes='54202f20485454502f312e310d0a557365722d4167656e743a206375726c2f372e32392e300d0a486f73743a203133352e3131312e3139302e3138333a32323338390d0a41') as a sequence because the decoded length of an embedded element exceeds the number of bytes remaining..  Data from client: [readBytes=47 45 54 20 2F 20 48 54 54 50 2F 31 2E 31 0D 0A 55 73 65 72 2D 41 67 65 6E 74 3A 20 63 75 72 6C 2F 37 2E 32 39 2E 30 0D 0A 48 6F 73 74 3A 20 31 33 35 2E 31 31 31 2E 31 39 30 2E 31 38 33 3A 32 32 33 38 39 0D 0A 41 unreadBytes=63 63 65 70 74 3A 20 2A 2F 2A 0D 0A 0D 0A]▒1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.20036
```

Comment: Hi, I'm having the difficulty to tell if this is the answer to this question. Shouldn't this part be included in the question? Also are you querying the dns server from one of the nodes? Does it work when you query it from the `Pod`?

Comment: thanks for your reply. and in the pod, I run curl ncs-1-dsx-1.default.bcmt01.nokia.com:22389, but it fails.

Comment: As I understand correctly, the answer that you've posted is not the answer to the question. I encourage you to delete it and to update your question with the contents of this post. Also as the `dig` command works, could you please check from the `Pod` if curl with `--dns-servers` works? `$ curl --dns-servers 10.254.0.10 curl ncs-1-dsx-1.default.bcmt01.nokia.com:22389`